# onclick add dropdown list data into a json array

Tags: jquery, json, struts2

I have an dropdown item like this

```
<s:select name="title" 
          list="%{rulemoduleVOList}"
          headerKey="0"
          headerValue="--Select--"
          listKey="id"
          listValue="name" 
          onchange="showStatCode()"
          id="moduleList" />
```

addition to this I placed an button

```
<input type="button" value="Add" />
```

When I click this button I need to add drop list selected data and its value with an iterator to json data for example:

after adding data the json array will be like this

```
[
    {"id":"100","name":"john","order":"1"},
    {"id":"120 ","name":"honey","order":"2"},
    {"id":"130 ","name":"benz","order":"3"},
    ...
]
```

NOTE:Each time when I add the json array should increase dynamically and I have one more button on click of it what ever data in the json array should be stored in to a database

Comment: I am totally new to JSON so help me with a solution

Comment: var jsonObject = [];
          var orderData=1;
          var jsonItem = {};
          jsonItem.id = $("#moduleList option:selected").val();
          jsonItem.name = $("#moduleList option:selected").text();
          jsonItem.order = orderData;
          jsonObject.push(jsonItem);

Comment: Now other pbm arised how to add this jsonobject into an jsonarray...each time when I add the array size increases